# 555 Timer for Motor Direction Control

Tags: motor, 555, back-emf

I am building a circuit to control the direction of a DC motor using two 555 timers. The circuit diagram is given below.

[image]

There will be a potentiometer and when it is turned to the rightmost position, the motor will rotate clockwise direction. When the potentiometer is turned to the leftmost position, the motor will rotate anticlockwise direction. When the potentiometer is in its center position, the motor will stop. The circuit is working as it supposed to be. But my concern is whether the timers will get damaged due to the back EMF from the motor. If yes, what kind of protection circuit I can add to this so that the timers can run the motor without any damage. [This](https://thinkrobotics.com/products/130-pony-micro-dc-motor-3v-6v) is the link of the motor that I am going to use in the circuit.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look to bidirectional DC motor control recommended in bridge drivers (like L298) datasheet, you will see 2 diodes in each output to limit the negative voltage to ground and positive to supply.

The main problem I see is that motor stall current is around 800 mA, and the maximum output of 555 is about 225 mA, that means you can easily damage the output transistors if the battery could supply that current.
Also capacitors are needed in main supply and in CV pin of both 555.

Comment: Generally agree, but the L298 is really obsolete tech; there's many alternatives that have much lower losses and hence work with lower supply voltages to the L298. Especially for beginners, I'd recommend against recommending the L298.

Comment: @MarcusMüller: Right,  only suggest what to look for diodes setup, many examples with that controller.

Comment: and that's why I upvoted you; it's just really a bad state of things that we keep recommending a bad controller because there's already many examples recommending the bad controller. Can't ever make progress that way!

Answer (score 0):

Simplest improvement would be this. It doesn't modify your existing design.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fDTwRM.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

However, it would be best to get a proper motor driver. It's not recommended to drive motors with 555 timers unless the current is well within the output specs including transients and loading. Your case might be on the design envelope and you are getting lucky that it's successful (all back EMF issues aside).

Answer (score 0):

It's really a bit surprising to use two 555 for a job that is totally not what a 555 is for. Use a single motor driver / H-bridge. Your 555 are not meant to drive inductive loads, nor are they even specified to drive high currents!

Typical hobbyist-friendly motor driver ICs include the DRV8833, or the DRV 8871 if you need higher voltages. The cheap AH9485/86 is already obsolete, but still much, much better than the commonly recommended L298.

All these motor drivers have inputs that allow you to select the direction of travel; the conversion of potentiometer position to forward / backward / off would be a job for a *window comparator* circuit. These circuits *can* be built with a 555 (because you already seem to have 555s lying around), but it's usually easier to just use an actual opamp / comparator for that. (And add histeresis).